# What is LLL can represent into luxonjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone, luxon

In my project, I have this in moment for time, this one,

```
  moment().format('LLL')    // June 9 2014 9:32 PM
  moment().format('D MMM YYYY[,] HH[:]mm z')
```

but if I use this in luxon how can i make this format in luxon, for example, given below,

```
   luxon.DateTime.utc().toFormat('')
   luxon.DateTime.now().toFormat('d MMM yyyy[,] HH[:]mm z')
```

Here if i use this, in luxon LLL it represents month as an abbreviated localized string and it might only show me the month only.

Comment: I would imagine that you should be able to take a look at the docs for moment and Luxon to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs.

moment.js

`LLL = Month name, day of month, year, time`

luxon.js

`LLL = month as an abbreviated localized string`

So looking a Luxon's docs,
the closest is `ff` but the month is short.
and `fff` but has the locale at the end.

If neither of those work for you, you could could maybe use.

`LLLL d, yyyy t a`

Comment: const format1 = 'fff';
const format3 = 'LLLL L, yyyy t';
console.log(`This fff into format Luxon -`, DateTime.local().toFormat(format1)); // This fff into format Luxon - 31 October 2022 at 12:00 WET
console.log(
  `This LLL into format Luxon 3 -`,
  DateTime.local().toFormat(format3)
); // October 10, 2022 12:00

const format2 = 'LLL';
console.log(`This LLL format moment -`, moment().format(format2)); // This LLL format moment - October 31, 2022 12:01 PM

Comment: I think fff works well, but i am not finding AM. It is showing local WET.

Comment: @GCT Yeah, the docs show it with AM, but `LLLL L, yyyy t a'` seems to be the same as moments.  eg. For me -> `toFormat('LLLL L, yyyy t a')` gives -> `October 10, 2022 12:05 PM`

Comment: Yes that also work for me when I add a that its showing the PM but the date in October 10 but not showing me local date October 31

Comment: @GCT  oops, yeah it should be -> `LLLL d, yyyy t a`